# Is there any way to log variables inside NDK except __android_log_print()?

Tags: android, logging, android-ndk

I can't see logs from NDK on one device. All other devices print logs fine, but one of devices ignores call `__android_log_print()`. But I need logs exactly from this device. Is there any other way to log info from NDK?

Comment: Are you asking how to output values from code you're writing (possible answer: open /sdcard/mylog.txt and use fprintf), or how to debug a non-functional /dev/log ?

Comment: @fadden "/sdcard/mylog.txt" would be enough. Thank you